# Use custom widget to override django JSONField

Tags: json, django, forms, widget

**I'm trying to use a 3-party widget like django-json-widget to edit the JSONField in my form.**

This is how my Form looks so far:

```
class ConfigsForm(forms.Form):
    ks_config = JSONField()
```

This code works fine, but the interface is quite ugly. I'm looking for something like *django-json-widget* package to be able to edit JSON data. But so far i wasn't able to implement it properly.
And here is my view for it:

```
def configs_details(request, sim_id):
    simulation = get_object_or_404(Simulation, pk=sim_id)
    
    ks_config = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'configs', str(simulation.uuid), 'ks_config.json')
    with open(ks_config) as jsn:

        form = ConfigsForm(request.POST or None,initial={'ks_config': json.load(jsn)})
        if form.is_valid():
            # validate and save
            pass

    template = 'sim_configuration.html'
    context = {'Form': form}
    return render(request,template, context)
```

**What I tried**.

Adding following lines to the form above:

```
class ConfigsForm(forms.Form):
    ks_config = JSONField()
    widgets = {
        'ks_config':  JSONEditorWidget(mode='code')
    }
```

Also, I have to specifically use Form and not ModelForm.

**Here is my HTML form page:**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block head %}
<title>Configs</title> {% endblock head %} {% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ Form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `{{ Form.media }}` on top of your form element

```
class ConfigsForm(forms.Form):
    ks_config = JSONField(widget=JSONEditorWidget(mode='code'))
```

```
<div class="container">
  {{ Form.media }}
  
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ Form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div></code></pre>
```

Comment: I've added this line and ran collectstatic command, but unfortunately, it's still the same.

Comment: @DuckPunk Also, provide the widget in the form field, edited